# Error: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception, ado.net, sql-insert

Hey all I'm trying to do the following insert query

```
SqlDataSource userQuizDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
userQuizDataSource.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=quizApp;Integrated Security=True";
userQuizDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [UserQuiz] ([DateTimeComplete], [Score], [UserName]) VALUES (@DateTimeComplete, @Score, @UserName)";

userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now.ToString());
userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("Score", score.ToString());
userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("UserName", User.Identity.Name);

int rowsAffected = userQuizDataSource.Insert();
```

Buti keep getting the following error:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type
>   to a smalldatetime data type resulted
>   in an out-of-range value.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does your statement `DateTime.Now.ToString()` return??

What language and regional settings is your SQL Server expecting??

Do you have a mismatch there??? Maybe your .NET returns a `MM/dd/yyyy` format, while SQL Server expects `dd/MM/yyyy` (or vice-versa).

Try this code in your SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (smalldate SMALLDATETIME)
INSERT INTO @test VALUES ('02/21/2010 22:00:32') --
SELECT * FROM @test
```

Replace my string there with what output you got from .NET's `DateTime.Now.ToString()` - does this work? Does SQL Server give you a better error message?

Next, try to use the ISO-8601 format for dates (YYYYMMDD) - this works for **ALL** regional and language settings in SQL Server - does this work??

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (smalldate SMALLDATETIME)
INSERT INTO @test VALUES ('20100221 22:00:32') --
SELECT * FROM @test
```

Comment: thanks alot ... that works !! i think the problem was more the fact that the format of the date on my machine is different to that of the server !!

Comment: .net returns date in the format of
dd/MM/yyyy
and when i checked SQL server the date formate is US style !!

Comment: The safest possible "date time" format from .net to sql I have used to date is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff".
PK :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem adding datetime.now into my SQL server column 'Date' set to datatype SmallDateTime.

To resolve it was quite simple (after many attempts!!)

```
string currentdatetime=
DateTime.Now.Year + "." + DateTime.Now.Month + "." + DateTime.Now.Day +
               " " + DateTime.Now.Hour+(":")+DateTime.Now.Minute+(":")+DateTime.Now.Second
```

This will return the date into the format that the Server will expect

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

to this:

```
userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("@startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Comment: im getting 2 new errors now
1)The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.Add(string, string)' has some invalid arguments
2)Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Answer (score 0):

Try no converting your date to string:

```
userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", DateTime.Now);
```

**Edit:** Try this then:

```
userQuizDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateTimeComplete", TypeCode.DateTime, DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

There is another way to just pass the actual object, but I can't remember.. sorry.

Comment: im getting 2 new errors now 1)The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.Add(string, string)' has some invalid arguments 2)Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string'

Comment: Sorry, you are right. There is actually another way to add just the object i.e. datetime but I cant remember, haven't got VS opened at the moment. Try it on the actual data source and look for a method something like AddParameterValue..(string name, object value)..

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8, if you are facing this problem even after changing `Formats` in below location

> Control Panel -> Region

You still have to transfer these settings to your users. In the same window, go to tab "Administrative", click on copy settings.

Select the appropriate check boxes and click `OK`.