# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.The statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonelBilgileri set ad=@ad,soyad=@soyad,DogumTarihi=@DogumTarihi,Telefon=@Telefon,Maas=@Maas,TcNo=@TcNo,GirisTarihi=@GirisTarihi,CıkısTarihi=@Cıkıstarihi WHERE PersonelID=3",baglan);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PersonelID", txtPersonelId.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ad", txtAd.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Soyad", txtSoyad.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DogumTarihi",DateTime.Now.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telefon", txtTelefon.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Maas", txtMaas.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TcNo", txtTckno.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GirisTarihi",DateTime.Now.ToString());
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CıkısTarihi",DateTime.Now.ToString());
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `.ToString()` after all of the `DateTime.Now`? If the columns are datetime then you don't need to convert to a string.

Comment: Do you know what would solve this? STOP USING `AddWithValue`

Comment: Yes ,i tried but it didn't work.

Comment: @JamesS what should ı do?

Comment: Try this cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GirisTarihi",DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 it didn't work

Comment: Please share what is error message.

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception: 'the conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.the statement has been terminated.'

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("GirisTarihi",SqlDbType.DateTime, DateTime.Now.ToString()); are you tried this one.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2307624/1364056 try this solution.

Comment: Remove `.ToString` and specify the type properly `cmd.Parameters.Add("GirisTarihi", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 Can addwithvalue take 3 arguments?

Comment: @senthilkumar2185 That is entirely unnecessary, it's a `datetime`, keep it as such and don't stringify it in the first place.

Comment: @Charlieface it didn't work

Comment: Did you change all of them, and are there any other columns which need to be parsed from `string` into `DateTime`?

Comment: nvarchar what is size you given pls chk could be reason also its failed. for example you fixed as 15 but passing values as 25 should be failed.

Comment: @Charlieface yes i changed them all

Comment: Show us DDL: `create table PersonelBilgileri ...`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov file:///C:/Users/enes_/OneDrive/Masaüstü/123123.png

Comment: Repeat: show us the script for creating a table. No need pictures! No need third-party sites! Just [edit] the question and paste the **text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the database is using datetime for the fields with DateTime.Now. So you will need to set the parameter as a Datetime

You can add this method again assuming it is DateTime. ( you need to check your Procedure as it could be Datetime2 or Date)

```
private static SqlParameter ToSqlParameterDateTime(DateTime? input, string strParameterName)
{
    var sqlparam = new SqlParameter(strParameterName, SqlDbType.DateTime)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    };
    if (input.HasValue)
        sqlparam.Value = input;
    else
    {
        sqlparam.Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    return (sqlparam);
}
```

Then change your method to be

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE PersonelBilgileri set ad=@ad,soyad=@soyad,DogumTarihi=@DogumTarihi,Telefon=@Telefon,Maas=@Maas,TcNo=@TcNo,GirisTarihi=@GirisTarihi,CıkısTarihi=@Cıkıstarihi WHERE PersonelID=3",baglan);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("PersonelID", txtPersonelId.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ad", txtAd.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Soyad", txtSoyad.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ToSqlParameterDateTime(DateTime.Now, “DogumTarihi"));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telefon", txtTelefon.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Maas", txtMaas.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TcNo", txtTckno.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ToSqlParameterDateTime(DateTime.Now, “GirisTarihi"));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(ToSqlParameterDateTime(DateTime.Now, “CıkısTarihi"));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: `ParameterDirection.Input` is the default anyway. And you could shorten it all to `cmd.Parameters.Add(“DogumTarihi", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;`