# Invalid datetime format. [...] The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Here is info about our technical development environment :

• .NET 6
• C# 10
• Hasura GraphQL v2.6.2-pro.1
• Micrsoft SQL server 2019
• Visual Studio 2022
• "GraphQL" version="7.3.1" Proxy
• "GraphQL.Client" version="5.1.1" Proxy
• "GraphQL.Client.Serializer.Newtonsoft" version="5.1.1" Proxy

I have application code that

1. Converts integer-based Unix timestamp into a C# DateTimeOffset
2. I convert said C# DateTimeOffset to a C# DateTime
3. The C# DateTime value is converted into a string-based DateTime format

Here is the code in question:

```
_DateCreated = DateTimeOffset
    .FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(emailEvent.TimeStamp)
    .DateTime
    .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Unfortunately, when I run the aforementioned code, I get the following error:

> {"Errors (1)\r\n1: Data exception. Invalid datetime format.
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server] The conversion
> of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an
> out-of-range value.\r\n"}

I searched the internet, and came across the this posting:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2307624/1338998

In the aforementioned posting, one of the commentors states the following:

> The safest possible "date time" format from .net to sql I have used to
> date is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff". PK :-)

Therefore, I changed my code in such way that the datetime’s string format would be different like in the following refactored code:

```
_DateCreated = DateTimeOffset
    .FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(emailEvent.TimeStamp)
    .DateTime
    .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Essentially, I changed the Datetime formatting of string from:

> …………..DateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

To

> ………………….DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"),

I no longer received the error.
However, my concern is whether the error throwing up really depends on the region date and time setting of the server that hosts my application.

To elaborate, my current server that host the application has the following region date and time settings:

[image]

Therefore, if someone changes said date and time format settings on the host server then the error might show up again regardless of what kind of C# datetime formatting that I use in my application code.

Therefore, I’m wondering if my C# datetime formatting would be in vain if the host server’s date and time format settings are changed.

How can I make changes to my C# datetime formatting code in such a way that it is more robust/fault-tolerant so that it will works regardless of the date and time format settings on the host server?

Comment: are you sure that's the actual code that errors? Because the error is coming from sql server, while your code looks to be plain simple c#

Comment: When I changed the C# code that formats the DateTime String value to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" , the error disappeared.  That's all I know.

Comment: Your error suggests SQL Server, but your question states PostgreSQL. Which is it?

Comment: Because that's an unambiguous format, @crazyTech . Ideally you should be passing strongly typed values to your queries and then (implicit) conversion errors can't occur.

Comment: @ThomA Sorry, I corrected listing.  It now says SQL Server.  In any case, Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "passing strongly typed values to your queries and then (implicit) conversion errors can't occur" ?  Furthermore, could you please provide some code sample solutions?

Comment: Pass a date time value to your SQL query, not a string. You can't have a conversion error to a date time if the value is *already* a date time.

Comment: As a side note the regional settings of the user on the device has *nothing* to do with how SQL Server interprets a literal string; that is defined by the sessions date format settings, which is normally tied to the `LOGIN`s language setting.

Comment: @ThomA  In my application code, C# code create and passes GraphQL String query---> Hasura GraphQL ---> MS SQL Server.    Hasura GraphQL query is passed as a string to Hasura GRaphQL instance.  I can Not pass SQL code directly.

Comment: Why are you using ODBC in C#? It would be better to use the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` managed library in .NET. Consider using ISO 8601 FORMAT with the `T` time separator ("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff"), which will work the same with `datetime` and `datetime2` data types. Without the separator, `datetime`  will reverse the month and day if the session setting is `DATEFORMAT YDM`.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** - if you're using `DateTime2` or `DateTimeOffset` in your database the rest of this answer doesn't apply to you.

However, if you're working with SQL Server's **`DateTime`** data type and use string representation of `DateTime` values, you should be using the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) human readable format,
which is `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`.

Using the Odbc format, which is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (almost the same as ISO 8601 but with a space instead of T as the separator between date and time parts) can cause errors or worst - wrong data, because the way SQL Server will convert it to `DateTime` depends on the login* Date format (which can be overriden if set directly in the query batch explicitly by using `SET DATEFORMAT`, or implicitly by using `SET LANGUAGE`).

*login means the SQL Server login that performed the query.

Here's some code to show what I mean:

```
DECLARE @Iso varchar(20) = '2023-09-13T16:18:32',
        @Odbc varchar(16) ='2023-09-13 16:18:32';

SELECT TRY_CAST(@Iso As DateTime) As Iso,
       TRY_CAST(@Odbc As DateTime) As Compact;

SET DateFormat YMD;

SELECT TRY_CAST(@Iso As DateTime) As Iso,
       TRY_CAST(@Odbc As DateTime) As Compact;

SET DateFormat YDM;

SELECT TRY_CAST(@Iso As DateTime) As Iso,
       TRY_CAST(@Odbc As DateTime) As Compact;
```

and it's results:

| Iso | Compact |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-09-13 16:18:32.000 | 2023-09-13 16:18:00.000 |

(DateFormat YMD)

| Iso | Compact |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-09-13 16:18:32.000 | 2023-09-13 16:18:00.000 |

(DateFormat YDM)

| Iso | Compact |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-09-13 16:18:32.000 | null |

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/2RhCrU4C)